# Handshake failure in SSLSocket (Java 8, Client/Server apps)

Tags: java, ssl, client, client-server

I'm developing two applications (Client and Server, both in Java) and I've decided to implement SSL communication for security. However each time I try to connect to server, client throws SSLHandshakeException: handshake_failure.

This is how server is created and run:

```
SSLServerSocket server = null;
SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
char[] passwd = "testing".toCharArray();        //password for testing purposes

try {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    FileInputStream store = new FileInputStream("<path to keystoke>");
    ks.load(store, passwd);
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ks, passwd);
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(ks);
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    server = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(8189);
} catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
while(!stopWork){
    SSLSocket incoming;
    Runnable r = null;
    try {
        incoming = (SSLSocket) server.accept();
        r = new ServerThread(incoming);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
...
```

And here is Client connecting:

```
public static void connectSSL(String ip) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(ip, 8189);
    socket.setSoTimeout(10_000);
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
    socket.startHandshake();   //<-Here exception happens
    input = socket.getInputStream();
    output = socket.getOutputStream();
    reader = new Scanner(input);
    writer = new PrintWriter(output,true);
    reader.nextLine();  //First ACK
}
```

Both client and server are being run on same machine within Eclipse with Java 8

Net logs:

```
... //Above were "adding as trusted cert
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
AWT-EventQueue-0, setSoTimeout(10000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1471803921 bytes = { 87, 7, 201, 99, 14, 195, 196, 196, 200, 75, 248, 103, 89, 111, 169, 159, 62, 88, 233, 205, 58, 118, 165, 27, 181, 16, 82, 172 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 209
0000: 01 00 00 CD 03 03 58 BA   F2 11 57 07 C9 63 0E C3  ......X...W..c..
0010: C4 C4 C8 4B F8 67 59 6F   A9 9F 3E 58 E9 CD 3A 76  ...K.gYo..>X..:v
0020: A5 1B B5 10 52 AC 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  ....R...d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 40 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00   17 00 18 00 19 00 09 00  @...............
00A0: 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00   0E 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 1C 00 1A 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 04 02 03 03 03   01 03 02 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00D0: 02                                                 .
AWT-EventQueue-0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 209
[Raw write]: length = 214
0000: 16 03 03 00 D1 01 00 00   CD 03 03 58 BA F2 11 57  ...........X...W
0010: 07 C9 63 0E C3 C4 C4 C8   4B F8 67 59 6F A9 9F 3E  ..c.....K.gYo..>
0020: 58 E9 CD 3A 76 A5 1B B5   10 52 AC 00 00 64 C0 24  X..:v....R...d.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 40 00 0A   00 16 00 14 00 17 00 18  .....@..........
00A0: 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00 0B   00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   04 02 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
00D0: 02 03 02 01 02 02                                  ......
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
AWT-EventQueue-0, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
AWT-EventQueue-0, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
AWT-EventQueue-0, called closeSocket()
AWT-EventQueue-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Comment: What does Java net logging indicate? `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Comment: I've included logging. Not sure what it means thou, so just pasted the ending part.